# Any good spell checkers for source code?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, spelling

I am constantly putting typos in my projects (google has officially ruined my spelling). Does anybody know of a plugin for VS or a general spell checker that will check string values that are in quotation marks (double and single), preferably free?

Answer (score 1):

A google search yielded this [VS Spell Check Add-on](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/12/13/spell-checker-for-html-asp-net-jscript-vb-c-css-and-c-for-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx)